# Como gerar o alfabeto com espaço em branco entre as letras?

Tags: string, haskell, range

Em Haskell eu posso gerar o alfabeto da seguinte forma:

```
alfabeto = ['a'..'z']
```

Para exibir ele basta:

```
alfabeto

"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Entretanto, eu gostaria de saber como eu posso colocar um espaço entre as letras, desta forma:

```
"a b c d e f g h ..."
```

## Dúvidas

1. Há alguma maneira de fazer isto?
2. Existe algum operador especifico que eu possa usar? Se sim, como eu devo utilizar ele?

Comment: Dúvida: o resultado deve ser `"a b c ... z"` ou `"a b c ... z "`, com relação ao último espaço?

Comment: `unwords [[x]|x <-['a'..'z']]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O módulo `Data.List` possui a função [`intersperse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersperse) que faz exatamente isso. Veja no GHCi:

```
Prelude> :m + Data.List
Prelude Data.List> intersperse ' ' ['a'..'z']
"a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"
```

Answer (score 3):

Se for possível manter o espaço ao final, após o caractere `z`, você pode mapear os caracteres concatenando com o espaço em branco e depois unir tudo em uma *string* com [`unwords`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=unwords):

```
> unwords (map(: " ")['a'..'z'])
"a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z "
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/LikelyIdioticMenu)</sup>